# Css hover over <span> doesn't work if there is a <tr> within?

Tags: html, css

Why won't `<span>` hover work when containing a `<tr>` in a `<table>` ?

Here is an example:

### html

```
<p>
    <table>
        <tr><td>
            <a>HOVER</td></tr><span><tr><td>child</td></tr></span></a>
       <tr><td> <span>immediate sibling</span>
           <span>general sibling</span></tr></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</p>
```

### css

```
p { font-size:20px; margin:20px; cursor:default; }
a { color:blue; border:3px solid blue; }
span { background:#ccc; }

span:hover { background:yellow; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UAHw7/22/

Comment: Make your markup valid first.

Comment: That's invalid HTML.  Your `a` cannot span cells or rows.

Comment: It is working. When you hover over "immediate sibling" and "general sibling" the background color chnages to yellow as per you CSS span:hover { background:yellow;

Answer (score 7):

Because a `<span>` isn't allowed there in the first place.

Use a [validator](http://validator.w3.org) to help you fix your HTML. Then worry about styling it.

Comment: You are using anchor tag splited over different tr. This is wrong html syntax. Your anchor tag should close first then ur td.

Answer (score 1):

It is invalid for a span to contain a table row; specifically, do not nest `<tr>` elements inside `<span>` elements.  As noted by Quentin, use an [HTML validator](http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/) (a different one from Quintin's; this allows you to past in HTML for validation).

The HTML in your fiddle is wrong in several ways; an anchor tag spanning multiple tr and td elements, a tr element nested inside a span tag and a bonus (what where you thinking?) tr ending tag.  Change your fiddle to this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a>HOVER</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span>child</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>immediate sibling</span>
            <span>general sibling</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Edit: removed the `<p>` because it cannot contain block elements (like `<table>`).

Answer (score 0):

```
<p><table>
<tr><td><span><a>HOVER</a></span></td></tr>
<tr><td>child</td></tr>
<tr><td> <span>immediate sibling</span>
<span>general sibling</span></tr></td>
</tr></table>
```

Is this you require...